# Issue with Jmeter while using a proxy server authentication using http requests

Tags: proxy, jmeter

I am trying to send the http request using our proxy server (hitting requests to access some content that should go through our proxy server) through JMeter for which I'm using HTTP Recording Controller, but I'm unable to get the response code 200

I have tried the test script recorder in Jmeter, but couldn't get a proper response code(200)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to record the test script and your organization is using a proxy server which is required to access the system under test - you need to [make JMeter aware of this proxy server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) by either providing proxy details as [command-line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options):

```
jmeter  -H your-proxy-host -P your-proxy-port -u username -a password
```

or via corresponding [JMeter system properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

```
http.proxyHost=your-proxy-host
http.proxyPort=your-proxy-port
https.proxyHost=your-proxy-host
https.proxyPort=your-proxy-port
```

additionally you might need to specify [`http.proxyDomain` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#proxy_config) in case of domain authentication

Comment: I tried adding these properties into jmeter.properties file but it does not take the proxy ip to send the requests